# Update ListView when updated list has got from server

Tags: android, rest, listview

How dynamically update the content of ListView?

App gets list from server and shows it. Also app caches this list for showing it to the user without delay. Somewhere in the future app will get updated list (update is small: two items was added, one was deleted).

How to detect changes and update only these items in ListView? Is there any complete solution?

Comment: What type of `Adapter` do you use?  Some code in your question would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArrayAdapter, you can use .add(), .addAll(), .remove() to change data of the Adapter. And then call .notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the view in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Here are codes to refresh `ListView` when its data source is changed.

```
List<Something> lists;
```

And your `Adapter` should like this:

```
public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private List<Something> mLists;
public MyAdapter(List<Something> lists){
    mLists = lists;
}
...
}
```

And initialize `Adapter`:
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(lists);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

And when lists changes and you want to refresh `ListView`, call like this:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or:

```
listview.notify();
```

Then you will see your `ListView` is changed.